# How can I put a System.IO.Stream into the Console?

Tags: c#

I got a `System.IO.Stream` from here

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpContent content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var webRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, targetUrl);
webRequest.Content = content;
var response = client.Send(webRequest);
```

Now I want to see with my eyes what is in that response. I tried:

```
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Of course, that would have been too easy so it didn't work.

Then

```
var f___ = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.Content.ReadAsStream()).ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine("Response:    " + f___);
```

No dice, just an empty string.

And even tried to be inventive...

```
response.Content.CopyTo(Console);
```

but that doesn't even compile.

The only thing I got to work was `Console.WriteLine("Headers " + response.Headers.ToString());` and that has a `content-length`, so I am expecting something.

Comment: I would have expected the version that reads from it as a stream to work... have you looked at the content length to check there really *is* some content?

Comment: Since you are probably handling text rather than a binary, I would use a `StreamReader` and a `Read(...) Write(...)` loop to copy to `Console.Out` so the encoding works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the **Content-Length** header and verify that there is actually content to read from the content stream:

```cs
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength
```

Perhaps you are reading the content of the response using another API, therefore leaving the stream position at the end of the stream? You can try seeking to the beginning and then reading the stream:

```cs
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

There are various ways to read the stream contents, some of which you have tried already:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// StreamReader
using var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

// Stream.CopyTo
stream.CopyTo(Console.OpenStandardOutput());

// Stream.Read
var length = (int) response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
var buffer = new byte[length];
var count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, count);

Console.WriteLine(text);

// HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync
var text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(text);

// HttpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync
var buffer = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```